# Answer-List Vote-Count in profile changes font-size on -9, not -10

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

A very small thing I just noticed while looking through [Evan Carolls answer list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/157251/evan-carroll?tab=answers) is that the vote-number changes its size if the votes reach `-9`; shouldn't it change the size if it hits `-10`?

Is this by design, or a simple typo?

[image: Picture]

Comment: Great, now do we address the bugs in the system that are responsible for those downvotes? Perhaps those design flaws can be fixed too.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Uh, you mean those nasty little bugs which some call 'users' or 'community'? Yeah, I don't like them, too...always breaking my software and stuff.

Comment: Are you from Austria, because if so your people have a reputation that makes me cautious when they refer to other people and communities as "bugs."

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Oh, I'd only start worrying if the term "untermensch" comes up again...I consider many users (without knowing anything about them, except their voice and so called 'knowledge') as major "bugs" which can not be fixed (and therefor need to be ignored)...though, that would explain why I'm not often allowed to speak to clients...

Comment: That the kicker with the Austrians though, one of them starts using the term "bugs" without the term "untermensch" and none of them are worried. Next you thing you know he uses the term but the rest are already on their way to being conquered. I'm suspicious, and I'm on to you.

Comment: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/NMghz.jpg](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NMghz.jpg)

Comment: If it answers your question, I never troll.

Comment: Ah, I *love* Franz Kafka! I think that story was fiction, though, so no reason to worry @EvanCarroll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in the next build (> `rev 2012.2.24.1225`).  Nice freehand pictures.

Comment: Well thank you. :) I had much practice since I joined Meta. ;)